# How do I define a new table that keys on one column but takes only the max (or min) of an additional text column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a fact table that looks like:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apples |
| 1 | Apple |
| 1 | Aples |
| 2 | Oranges |

I'd like to define a new table, perhaps using SummarizeColumns, based on that fact table that only uses the first verbose product name found for each ID. So...

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apples |
| 2 | Oranges |

In SQL this would be as simple as:

```
select ID, max(Name) as Name from SomeTable group by ID
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically you manufacture dimensions in Power Query rather than DAX, but the new [DAX Window Functions](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-window-functions-in-dax) make this simple.

```
  DimFruit = 
    INDEX(
    1,
    ALL('Fact'[FruitID],'Fact'[Name]), 
    ORDERBY(len('Fact'[Name]),DESC),
    KEEP,
    PARTITIONBY('Fact'[FruitID])
    )
```